# Correct way to remove a UIViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In an app with several ViewControllers added in a storyboard, I need to modify the hierarchy.

Lets say I have these two flows:

> 1. A ---> B ---> C ---> A
> 2. A ---> B ---> C ---> B (I want the second B to be a new instance)

In scenario 1 I believe that this should work:

```
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

But I can't seem to get how to achieve scenario 2.

One option I think about is modifying the stack, but it seems like it's not the right approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NavigationController.ViewControllers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (NavigationController.ViewControllers[i] is MyNotSoAmazingVc)
            {
                //some code to remove it
                break;
            }
        }
```

How can I remove B and create a new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious if you are wanting to keep the first B in memory, you can just push a new segue to B. Every time a segue is performed, a new instance of that view controller is created (be careful with memory management).

If you're looking to remove B from the view controller stack and then make a new instance of B, you can do this:

```
var controllers = this.NavigationController.ViewControllers;
var newcontrollers = new UIViewController[controllers.Length - 1];
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in controllers)
{
    if (!(item.GetType() == typeof(ViewControllerB)))
    {
        newcontrollers[index] = item;
        index++;
    }
}
this.NavigationController.ViewControllers = newcontrollers;
```

This will remove B from the view controller stack. You will then need to perform a segue to B to get a new instance on in there. You will then have A -> C -> B.

This could probably be optimized a bit. Additionally, if you know ViewControllerB will always be at position 2 (or position 1 depending how you look at it), you can simply remove it by index. The code I gave you will always remove B no matter where it's at or how many Bs there are.

Answer (score 0):

to remove B controller from navigation stack:

```
//some code to remove it    
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```